# Could not autowire. No beans of 'EntityManager' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

trying spring boot, in video said, that the bean for entityManager spring creating automaticly, and in video guy havnt problems.
but in my case i have an error `Could not autowire. No beans of 'EntityManager' type found.`

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 
   @Repository
    public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    
        @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;//Could not autowire. No beans of 'EntityManager' type found. 
    
        @Override
        public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            Query<Employee> query = session.createQuery("from Employee ", Employee.class);
            List<Employee> allEmployees = query.getResultList();
            return allEmployees;
        }
```

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-entitymanager you should use `@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;`

Comment: Make sure that you've added all relevant dependencies (hibernate or spring-orm or similar) to your application bundle

Answer (score 2):

From version 6.0 Hibernate uses jakarta.persistence rather than javax. Change the import and use the @PersistenceContext annotation